# How to fix CVE-2019-8457 vulnerability in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite, security, amazon-ecr

How to fix CVE-2019-8457 vulnerability in Spring Boot application, since none of my known dependencies includes SQLite3 in Spring Boot 2.6.6, jdk18-slim docker image

```
CVE-2019-8457   
db5.3:5.3.28+dfsg1-0.8  
HIGH    

SQLite3 from 3.6.0 to and including 3.27.2 is vulnerable to heap out-of-bound read in the rtreenode() function when handling invalid rtree tables.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use alpine version of container images which mostly does not have high and critical vulnerabilities

Answer (score 2):

Please inspect the dependency tree of your project to check if there is a transitive dependency defined on **sqlite3**. You may not be using **sqlite3** directly in the project dependencies, there is a chance that some other library has defined it as a dependency.

For maven.

```bash
mvn dependency:tree
```

For gradle.

```bash
gradle dependencies
```

Once you find it, use exclusion pattern to exclude the older version of **sqlite3** and explicitly declare a dependency of **sqlite3** with the fixed version of **sqlite3** version.

Comment: interestingly sqlite3 is not part of the dependencies, am assuming its part of the base docker image